# How to write login plugin to MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I want to connect to our own oauth2 server, so I wrote an oauth2 login extension, there is the code when I get account information from oauth2 server.

```
$user = User::newFromName($username);
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->load();

if (!($user instanceof User && $user->getId())) {
    $user->addToDatabase();
}

$user->setToken();
$user->setCookies();
$this->getContext()->setUser($user);
$user->saveSettings();
```

It will create user data if the user does not exist, but sometimes login will fail if you are not logout by click logout button, and I totally have no clue to solve this problem.

I found MediaWiki has login [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=login), but it required a password and seems not has user auto-creating feature, any reference to accomplish it?

Comment: Note that setting the email before loading the user does not do anything useful.

Comment: But I indeed login, just logout soon if not doing anything, but it's not about the server session timeout, I am trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

In MediaWiki 1.27+ login should be done by writing a [`PrimaryAuthenticationProvider`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager#PrimaryAuthenticationProvider) (before 1.27 there was no non-hacky way to do it for non-password-based logins). See the inline documentation in that class, or [this patch](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/251930/) which provides similar functionality for OAuth1.

Comment: But many extensions like MW-OAuth2Client and LDAP extension all do the login without password, the code is taking MW-OAuth2Client as reference, and it's indeed login, but will logout soon if not doing anything on the page, and it's not about server session timeout, because I set it to expire after 24 hours, I am still trying to figure it out

Comment: LDAP uses password-based authentication; MediaWiki up to 1.26 used AuthPlugin for that, MW 1.27+ uses PrimaryAuthenticationProvider. For passwordless login like OAuth pre-1.27 code usually just created some sort of alternative login page (with all kinds of ill side effects).

Comment: I know LDAP is password-based, but I am sure LDAP plugin is not used password when login, the user_password and user_newpassword column is empty in database when user was login via LDAP, and you are right, I create a special page for Oauth2 login, and It actually works, but will auto-logout around 5 minutes if you don't do anything on page, I am stuck in there.